# Creating a simple plugin system in php

Tags: php, plugins

I'am writing an online software. I need to integrate a simple plugin system in it like wordpress (add action, add filter etc.)

What is the simplest way to do it in PHP?

Comment: If you are referring to WP, why don't just take a look there?

Comment: @zerkms In my experience, I would never recommend someone look at WordPress's code for reference.

Comment: @alex: so do I (despite the fact I never seen WP code), but he wants the plugin system **like the one in WP**. So at least from this point - it is worth to look there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer: The best way is to just write it yourself and find out.

Instead of assuming you need a plugin system, write your app first. Then you'll start to get an idea of exactly what your app needs.

Solving that problem will make you a much better programmer. And once you know your app intimately, and you're tired of re-writing code and reinventing the wheel, and you want to start simplifying it and making it *reusable*, then making a plugin system will be second nature. You won't even have to think about it.

Take a look at Eric S. Raymond's [Rules of Unix Programming](http://catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html). They're inspiring, fun to read, and very relevant here.

Comment: great answer for writing program.. thak you for main idea.

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

> The observer pattern (a subset of the publish/subscribe pattern) is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods. It is mainly used to implement distributed event handling systems.

[This article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/5) looks like a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of design patterns exist to do so but the easiest and simplest way, to me, would be with a simple class interface followed by all your plugins.